# php fatal call to member function prepare() on non object

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo, prepare

Been looking everywhere for an answer as to why my pdo prepare() function is giving me this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/database.class.php on line 26

I have been looking at every post about this but none of them seem to help or even just clear up this error. I started here: http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/ 
a havent changed anything just trying to use it with POST data

this is my database.class.php:

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "nicholas";
    private $pass = "12345";
    private $dbname = "sstest";

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    public $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();    
        }
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);    //this is line 26
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                break;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
        return $this->stmt->execute();  
    }

    public function resultSet() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO_::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCount() {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount(); 
    }

    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();  
    }

    public function beginTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();  
    }

    public function endTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }

    public function cancelTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }


}

?>
```

and here is the php file using my database:

```
<?php
include 'database.class.php';

$id = $_POST["id"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];

$database = new Database();

$sql = 'INSERT INTO sstest (id, fname, lname) VALUES (:id, :fname, :lname)';

$database->query($sql);

$database->bind(':id', $id);
$database->bind(':fname', $fname);
$database->bind(':lname', $lname);

$database->execute();

echo $database->lastInsertId();
?>
```

I know the java code is sending the POST data, but i am confused as to why the prepare() function is saying $sql is a non-object. Any help is much appreciated, ive been working on this for 2 days now and am not able to get past the prepare() statement.

Comment: *"I know the java code is sending the POST data"* --- What java?

Comment: Well you are catching your pdo errors then doing nothing with them. Check $this->error

Comment: The database connection simply fails and the object is not instanced, if you'd have the method on the *wrong* object, it would be `undefined function of object ....` but it sais `non-object`.

Comment: Fred I didn't post the java code cuz there isn't an issue with it......but thanks I'm gonna check that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
try {
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();    
}
```

Add this line to catch after the line you have there:

```
var_dump($this->error);exit();
```

Comment: thank you! i was able to see what was causing the pdo exception, i was only looking in my apache error log previously.....but this was due misreferenced databases, thank you again for the answer....will be accepting in a minute